# Take UNIQUE rows value under conditions

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a G-spreadsheet where I applied an API connector, that takes data (invoices data) from an external DB; every day the G-sheet receives the last 250 rows Data from the external DB, so some rows are news and others are repeated and added again below in the list.

Usually, I have 2-3 times repeated rows with the same information and sometimes I can have repeated value like: invoiceID - invoice number - ecc., but with a different amount (because the administration system sometimes has to correct the invoices).

My question is How can I create a formula in a new sheet collecting the UNIQUE newest values of the repeated rows?

As you can see the Fetch date is the API connector that for 3 days repeated the value, and on 29 it gots a different amount after correction of the invoice from the admin department.

[image: sample here]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: The desired output would be another sheet with only the 3º row, with the newest Data: 2019-11-29 and the right price of 23,5€.

Answer (score 0):

try `SORTN` with the 3rd parameter set to `2`:

```
=SORTN(SORT(B2:G; 1; 0); 99^99; 2; 5; 0)
```